# Two filter drivers in one binary causes System error 2 on the 2nd driver

Tags: c, windows, networking, driver, ndis

I have two NDIS filter drivers in the same binary. This seems to work based on [this MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/09c04b7d-af93-4c43-ae8f-76d024ae62de/is-it-possible-to-have-two-filter-drivers-in-one-binary-on-windows?forum=wdk).

I encountered an issue: Both drivers have been successfully installed using `NetCfg API`. However, the second installed driver won't start. It causes `System error 2`:

```
C:\Program Files\Npcap>net start npcap
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.


C:\Program Files\Npcap>net start npcap_wifi
System error 2 has occurred.


The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I install `npcap_wifi` first, `npcap` second, then `npcap` service fails to start. DbgView shows that the second driver's `DriverEntry` is never called. And the NetCfg API install doesn't show any error either. So I don't know what's wrong here? Thanks!

---

My source code:

The 1st driver's INF is: [npcap.inf](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/blob/master/packetWin7/npf/npf/npcap.inf). It uses service name `npcap`.

The 2nd driver's INF is: [npcap_wifi.inf](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/blob/master/packetWin7/npf/npf/npcap_wifi.inf) It uses service name `npcap_wifi`.

The shared binary is: [Packet.c](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/blob/master/packetWin7/npf/npf/Packet.c). I used `DriverEntry`'s `RegistryPath` to determine which service the binary is running as.

The driver installer is: [NPFInstall.cpp](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/blob/master/packetWin7/NPFInstall/NPFInstall/NPFInstall.cpp). The command `NPFInstall.exe -i` is used to install the 1st driver and `NPFInstall.exe -i2` is used to install the 2nd driver.

---

UPDATE:

I have modified `npcap.inf` based on your fake service method:

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; NPCAP.INF -- Npcap NDIS 6.x LightWeight Filter Driver
;
; Copyright (c) 2015, Insecure.Com LLC.  All rights reserved.
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
[version]
Signature       = "$Windows NT$"
Class           = NetService
ClassGUID       = {4D36E974-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
CatalogFile     = %NPF_DriverName%.cat
Provider        = %Insecure%
DriverVer=05/15/2015,14.48.38.905


[Manufacturer]
%Insecure%=Insecure,NTx86,NTia64,NTamd64

[Insecure.NTx86]
%NPF_Desc_Standard%=FilterStandard, INSECURE_NPCAP
%NPF_Desc_WiFi%=FilterWiFi, INSECURE_NPCAP_WIFI

[Insecure.NTia64]
%NPF_Desc_Standard%=FilterStandard, INSECURE_NPCAP
%NPF_Desc_WiFi%=FilterWiFi, INSECURE_NPCAP_WIFI

[Insecure.NTamd64]
%NPF_Desc_Standard%=FilterStandard, INSECURE_NPCAP
%NPF_Desc_WiFi%=FilterWiFi, INSECURE_NPCAP_WIFI

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Installation Section
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[FilterStandard]
NetCfgInstanceId="{7daf2ac8-e9f6-4765-a842-f1f5d2501341}"
Copyfiles = npf.copyfiles.sys
Characteristics=0x40000
AddReg=FilterStandard.reg

[FilterWiFi]
NetCfgInstanceId="{7daf2ac8-e9f6-4765-a842-f1f5d2501351}"
Characteristics=0x40000
AddReg=FilterWiFi.reg

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%NPF_Desc_Standard%,"",,

[SourceDisksFiles]
npcap.sys=1

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=12
npf.copyfiles.sys=12

[npf.copyfiles.sys]
%NPF_DriverName%.sys,,,2


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Ndi installation support for the standard filter
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[FilterStandard.reg]
HKR, Ndi,Service,,%NPF_Filter_Name_Standard%
HKR, Ndi,CoServices,0x00010000,%NPF_Filter_Name_Standard%
HKR, Ndi,HelpText,,%NPF_HelpText%
HKR, Ndi,FilterClass,, compression


; For a Monitoring filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 1 ; Monitoring filter
; For a Modifying filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 2 ; Modifying filter
HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001,2


HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,UpperRange, , noupper
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange, , "ndis5,ndis4"


; TODO: Ensure that the list of media types below is correct.  Typically,
; filters include "ethernet".  Filters may also include "ppip" to include
; native WWAN stacks, but you must be prepared to handle the packet framing.
; Possible values are listed on MSDN, but common values include:
;     ethernet, wan, ppip, wlan
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, FilterMediaTypes,,"ethernet, fddi, wan, ppip, wlan, bluetooth, ndis5, vwifi, flpp4, flpp6, vchannel, nolower"


; For a Mandatory filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 1 ; Mandatory filter
; For an Optional filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 2 ; Optional filter
HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 2 ; Optional filter


; By default, Mandatory filters unbind all protocols when they are
; installed/uninstalled, while Optional filters merely pause the stack.  If you
; would like to override this behavior, you can include these options.  These
; options only take effect with 6.30 filters on Windows "8" or later.
; To prevent a full unbind, and merely pause/restart protocols:
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnAttach,0x00010001, 0 ; Do not unbind during FilterAttach
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnDetach,0x00010001, 0 ; Do not unbind during FilterDetach
; To force a full unbind/bind (which includes pause/restart, of course):
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnAttach,0x00010001, 1 ; Unbind during FilterAttach
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnDetach,0x00010001, 1 ; Unbind during FilterDetach
;

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Ndi installation support for the WiFi filter
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[FilterWiFi.reg]
HKR, Ndi,Service,,%NPF_Filter_Name_WiFi%
HKR, Ndi,CoServices,0x00010000,%NPF_Filter_Name_WiFi%
HKR, Ndi,HelpText,,%NPF_HelpText%
HKR, Ndi,FilterClass,, ms_medium_converter_128


; For a Monitoring filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 1 ; Monitoring filter
; For a Modifying filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 2 ; Modifying filter
HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001,2


HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,UpperRange, , noupper
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces,LowerRange, , "ndis5,ndis4"


; TODO: Ensure that the list of media types below is correct.  Typically,
; filters include "ethernet".  Filters may also include "ppip" to include
; native WWAN stacks, but you must be prepared to handle the packet framing.
; Possible values are listed on MSDN, but common values include:
;     ethernet, wan, ppip, wlan
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, FilterMediaTypes,,"ethernet, fddi, wan, ppip, wlan, bluetooth, ndis5, vwifi, flpp4, flpp6, vchannel, nolower"


; For a Mandatory filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 1 ; Mandatory filter
; For an Optional filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 2 ; Optional filter
HKR, Ndi,FilterRunType,0x00010001, 2 ; Optional filter


; By default, Mandatory filters unbind all protocols when they are
; installed/uninstalled, while Optional filters merely pause the stack.  If you
; would like to override this behavior, you can include these options.  These
; options only take effect with 6.30 filters on Windows "8" or later.
; To prevent a full unbind, and merely pause/restart protocols:
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnAttach,0x00010001, 0 ; Do not unbind during FilterAttach
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnDetach,0x00010001, 0 ; Do not unbind during FilterDetach
; To force a full unbind/bind (which includes pause/restart, of course):
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnAttach,0x00010001, 1 ; Unbind during FilterAttach
;     HKR, Ndi,UnbindOnDetach,0x00010001, 1 ; Unbind during FilterDetach
;

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Service installation support
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[FilterStandard.Services]
AddService=%NPF_Filter_Name_Standard%,,FilterStandard.svc

[FilterWiFi.Services]
AddService=%NPF_Filter_Name_WiFi%,,FilterWiFi.svc

[FilterStandard.svc]
DisplayName     = %NPF_Desc_Standard%
ServiceType     = 1 ;SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType       = 3 ;SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl    = 1 ;SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary   = %12%\%NPF_DriverName%.sys
LoadOrderGroup  = NDIS
Description     = %NPF_Desc_Standard%
AddReg          = Common.Params.reg, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions.reg

[FilterWiFi.svc]
DisplayName     = %NPF_Desc_WiFi%
ServiceType     = 1 ;SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType       = 3 ;SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl    = 1 ;SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary   = %12%\%NPF_DriverName%.sys
LoadOrderGroup  = NDIS
Description     = %NPF_Desc_WiFi%
AddReg          = Common.Params.reg, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions.reg

[FilterStandard.Remove.Services]
DelService=%NPF_Filter_Name_Standard%,0x200 ; SPSVCINST_STOPSERVICE

[FilterWiFi.Remove.Services]
DelService=%NPF_Filter_Name_WiFi%,0x200 ; SPSVCINST_STOPSERVICE

[Common.Params.reg]

[NdisImPlatformBindingOptions.reg]
HKR, Parameters, NdisImPlatformBindingOptions,0x00010001,0 ; Subscribe to default behavior

[Strings]
NPF_DriverName = "npcap"
NPF_Filter_Name_Standard = "npcap"
NPF_Filter_Name_WiFi = "npcap_wifi"
Insecure = "Nmap Project"
NPF_Desc_Standard = "Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP)"
NPF_Desc_WiFi = "Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP) (Wi-Fi)"
NPF_HelpText = "A NDIS 6 filter driver & WFP callout driver to support packet capturing and sending under Windows 7, 8 & 10"
```

And my installer code is changed to:

```
HRESULT HrInstallNetComponent(IN INetCfg* pnc, IN LPCTSTR lpszComponentId, IN const GUID* pguidClass, IN LPCTSTR lpszInfFullPath)
{
    DWORD dwError;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    TCHAR szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    TCHAR szDir[_MAX_DIR];
    TCHAR szDirWithDrive[_MAX_DRIVE + _MAX_DIR];

    //
    // If full path to INF has been specified, the INF
    // needs to be copied using Setup API to ensure that any other files
    // that the primary INF copies will be correctly found by Setup API
    //
    if (lpszInfFullPath)
    {
        //
        // Get the path where the INF file is.
        //
        _tsplitpath(lpszInfFullPath, szDrive, szDir, NULL, NULL);

        _tcscpy(szDirWithDrive, szDrive);
        _tcscat(szDirWithDrive, szDir);

        //
        // Copy the Service INF file to the \Windows\Inf Folder
        //
        if (!SetupCopyOEMInfW(lpszInfFullPath, szDirWithDrive, // Other files are in the
            // same dir. as primary INF
            SPOST_PATH,    // First param is path to INF
            0,             // Default copy style
            NULL,          // Name of the INF after
            // it's copied to %windir%\inf
            0,             // Max buf. size for the above
            NULL,          // Required size if non-null
            NULL)          // Optionally get the filename
            // part of Inf name after it is copied.
           )
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();

            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
        }
    }

    if (S_OK == hr)
    {
        //
        // Install the network component.
        //
        hr = HrInstallComponent(pnc, NDISLWF_SERVICE_PNP_DEVICE_ID, pguidClass);

        if (hr == S_OK)
        {
            hr = HrInstallComponent(pnc, NDISLWF_SERVICE_PNP_DEVICE_ID_WIFI, pguidClass);

            if (hr == S_OK)
            {
                //
                // On success, apply the changes
                //
                hr = pnc->Apply();
            }
        }
    }

    return hr;
}
```

And the result is the second service `npcap_wifi` ends up with system error 2:

```
C:\Program Files\Npcap>sc query npcap

SERVICE_NAME: npcap
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Program Files\Npcap>sc query npcap_wifi
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.


C:\Program Files\Npcap>sc query npcap
SERVICE_NAME: npcap
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Program Files\Npcap>sc query npcap_wifi

SERVICE_NAME: npcap_wifi
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 2  (0x2)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Program Files\Npcap>net start npcap
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.


C:\Program Files\Npcap>net start npcap_wifi
System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.


C:\Program Files\Npcap>
```

Does this look right? The question is I still don't get the `DriverEntry` call for the 2nd LWF in DbgView? So how the 2nd LWF work then?

---

UPDATE:

I guess this is what I should do next? I called `NdisFRegisterFilterDriver` twice in my `DriverEntry` to register 2 LWFs. The 2 `FChars` structures only differ in `FriendlyName, UniqueName, ServiceName`. But the 2nd `NdisFRegisterFilterDriver` always fails with `NDIS_STATUS_FAILURE` (0xc0000001). I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
//
//  Packet Driver's entry routine.
//
_Use_decl_annotations_
NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    )
{
    NDIS_FILTER_DRIVER_CHARACTERISTICS FChars;
    NDIS_FILTER_DRIVER_CHARACTERISTICS FChars_WiFi;
    NTSTATUS Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    // Use NonPaged Pool instead of No-Execute (NX) Nonpaged Pool for Win8 and later, this is for security purpose.
    ExInitializeDriverRuntime(DrvRtPoolNxOptIn);

    WCHAR* bindT;
    PKEY_VALUE_PARTIAL_INFORMATION tcpBindingsP;
    UNICODE_STRING macName;
    ULONG OsMajorVersion, OsMinorVersion;
    NDISGROUPMAXPROCESSORCOUNT MyNdisGroupMaxProcessorCount;
    NDIS_STRING GroupMaxProcessorCount;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    TRACE_ENTER();
    FilterDriverObject = DriverObject;

    PsGetVersion(&OsMajorVersion, &OsMinorVersion, NULL, NULL);
    TRACE_MESSAGE2(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "OS Version: %d.%d\n", OsMajorVersion, OsMinorVersion);

    // RegistryPath = "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\npcap" for standard driver
    // RegistryPath = "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\npcap_wifi" for WiFi driver
    g_Dot11SupportMode = 0;
    for (USHORT i = 0; i < RegistryPath->Length / 2; i ++)
    {
        if (RegistryPath->Buffer[i] == L'_')
        {
            g_Dot11SupportMode = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "g_Dot11SupportMode (based on RegistryPath) = %d\n", g_Dot11SupportMode);

    if (g_Dot11SupportMode)
        NdisInitUnicodeString(&g_NPF_Prefix, g_NPF_PrefixBuffer_Wifi);
    else
        NdisInitUnicodeString(&g_NPF_Prefix, g_NPF_PrefixBuffer);

    //
    // Get number of CPUs and save it
    //
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&GroupMaxProcessorCount, L"NdisGroupMaxProcessorCount");
    MyNdisGroupMaxProcessorCount = (NDISGROUPMAXPROCESSORCOUNT) NdisGetRoutineAddress(&GroupMaxProcessorCount);
    if (MyNdisGroupMaxProcessorCount) // for NDIS620 and later (Win7 and later).
    {
        g_NCpu = MyNdisGroupMaxProcessorCount(ALL_PROCESSOR_GROUPS);
        TRACE_MESSAGE2(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "g_NCpu (NdisGroupMaxProcessorCount): %d, NPF_MAX_CPU_NUMBER: %d\n", g_NCpu, NPF_MAX_CPU_NUMBER);
        if (g_NCpu > NPF_MAX_CPU_NUMBER)
        {
            g_NCpu = NPF_MAX_CPU_NUMBER;
        }
    }
    else // for NDIS6 (Vista)
    {
        g_NCpu = NdisSystemProcessorCount();
    }

    //
    // Register as a service with NDIS
    //
    NPF_registerLWF(&FChars, FALSE);
    NPF_registerLWF(&FChars_WiFi, TRUE);

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = NPF_Unload;

    //
    // Standard device driver entry points stuff.
    //
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = NPF_OpenAdapter;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = NPF_CloseAdapter;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLEANUP] = NPF_Cleanup;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = NPF_Read;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_WRITE] = NPF_Write;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = NPF_IoControl;

    bindP = getAdaptersList();

    if (bindP == NULL)
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Adapters not found in the registry, try to copy the bindings of TCP-IP.");

        tcpBindingsP = getTcpBindings();

        if (tcpBindingsP == NULL)
        {
            TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "TCP-IP not found, quitting.");
            goto RegistryError;
        }

        bindP = (WCHAR *)tcpBindingsP;
        bindT = (WCHAR *)(tcpBindingsP->Data);
    }
    else
    {
        bindT = bindP;
    }

    for (; *bindT != UNICODE_NULL; bindT += (macName.Length + sizeof(UNICODE_NULL)) / sizeof(WCHAR))
    {
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&macName, bindT);
        NPF_CreateDevice(DriverObject, &macName);
    }

    // Register the filter to NDIS.
    Status = NdisFRegisterFilterDriver(DriverObject,
        (NDIS_HANDLE) FilterDriverObject,
        &FChars,
        &FilterDriverHandle);
    if (Status != NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: failed to register filter with NDIS, Status = %x", Status);
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return Status;
    }
    else
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE2(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: succeed to register filter with NDIS, Status = %x, FilterDriverHandle = %x", Status, FilterDriverHandle);
    }

    // Register the WiFi filter to NDIS.
    Status = NdisFRegisterFilterDriver(DriverObject,
        (NDIS_HANDLE)FilterDriverObject,
        &FChars_WiFi,
        &FilterDriverHandle_WiFi);
    if (Status != NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: failed to register filter (WiFi) with NDIS, Status = %x", Status);
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return Status;
    }
    else
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE2(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: succeed to register filter (WiFi) with NDIS, Status = %x, FilterDriverHandle_WiFi = %x", Status, FilterDriverHandle_WiFi);
    }

#ifdef HAVE_WFP_LOOPBACK_SUPPORT
    // Use Winsock Kernel (WSK) to send loopback packets.
    Status = NPF_WSKStartup();
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    {
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return Status;
    }

    Status = NPF_WSKInitSockets();
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    {
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return Status;
    }
#endif

    NdisAllocateSpinLock(&g_OpenArrayLock);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;

RegistryError:

    Status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    TRACE_EXIT();
    return(Status);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
VOID
NPF_registerLWF(
    PNDIS_FILTER_DRIVER_CHARACTERISTICS pFChars,
    BOOLEAN bWiFiOrNot
    )
{
    NDIS_STRING FriendlyName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(NPF_SERVICE_DESC_WIDECHAR); // display name
    NDIS_STRING UniqueName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(FILTER_UNIQUE_NAME); // unique name, quid name
    NDIS_STRING ServiceName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(NPF_DRIVER_NAME_SMALL_WIDECHAR); // this to match the service name in the INF
    NDIS_STRING FriendlyName_WiFi = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(NPF_SERVICE_DESC_WIDECHAR_WIFI); // display name
    NDIS_STRING UniqueName_WiFi = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(FILTER_UNIQUE_NAME_WIFI); // unique name, quid name
    NDIS_STRING ServiceName_WiFi = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(NPF_DRIVER_NAME_SMALL_WIDECHAR_WIFI); // this to match the service name in the INF

    NdisZeroMemory(pFChars, sizeof(NDIS_FILTER_DRIVER_CHARACTERISTICS));
    pFChars->Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_FILTER_DRIVER_CHARACTERISTICS;
    pFChars->Header.Size = sizeof(NDIS_FILTER_DRIVER_CHARACTERISTICS);
#if NDIS_SUPPORT_NDIS61
    pFChars->Header.Revision = NDIS_FILTER_CHARACTERISTICS_REVISION_2;
#else
    pFChars->Header.Revision = NDIS_FILTER_CHARACTERISTICS_REVISION_1;
#endif

    pFChars->MajorNdisVersion = NDIS_FILTER_MAJOR_VERSION; // NDIS version is 6.2 (Windows 7)
    pFChars->MinorNdisVersion = NDIS_FILTER_MINOR_VERSION;
    pFChars->MajorDriverVersion = 1; // Driver version is 1.0
    pFChars->MinorDriverVersion = 0;
    pFChars->Flags = 0;

    // Use different names for the WiFi driver.
    if (bWiFiOrNot)
    {
        pFChars->FriendlyName = FriendlyName_WiFi;
        pFChars->UniqueName = UniqueName_WiFi;
        pFChars->ServiceName = ServiceName;
        // pFChars->ServiceName = ServiceName_WiFi;
    }
    else
    {
        pFChars->FriendlyName = FriendlyName;
        pFChars->UniqueName = UniqueName;
        pFChars->ServiceName = ServiceName;
    }

    pFChars->SetOptionsHandler = NPF_RegisterOptions;
    pFChars->AttachHandler = NPF_AttachAdapter;
    pFChars->DetachHandler = NPF_DetachAdapter;
    pFChars->RestartHandler = NPF_Restart;
    pFChars->PauseHandler = NPF_Pause;
    pFChars->SetFilterModuleOptionsHandler = NPF_SetModuleOptions;
    pFChars->OidRequestHandler = NPF_OidRequest;
    pFChars->OidRequestCompleteHandler = NPF_OidRequestComplete;
    pFChars->CancelOidRequestHandler = NPF_CancelOidRequest;

    pFChars->SendNetBufferListsHandler = NPF_SendEx;
    pFChars->ReturnNetBufferListsHandler = NPF_ReturnEx;
    pFChars->SendNetBufferListsCompleteHandler = NPF_SendCompleteEx;
    pFChars->ReceiveNetBufferListsHandler = NPF_TapEx;
    pFChars->DevicePnPEventNotifyHandler = NPF_DevicePnPEventNotify;
    pFChars->NetPnPEventHandler = NPF_NetPnPEvent;
    pFChars->StatusHandler = NPF_Status;
    pFChars->CancelSendNetBufferListsHandler = NPF_CancelSendNetBufferLists;
}
```

For the 2nd LWF, I used the 1st LWF's `ServiceName` (`npcap`), or used its own `npcap_wifi`, neither works.

The entire source code is here: https://github.com/nmap/npcap/commit/1cac59271a9772ebbfff0db9c8a051b6553c25a2

---

UPDATE:

I analyzed the WPP trace, it shows:

```
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]==>NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: DriverObject FFFF8A85572FD6D0, Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP)
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]==>ndisCreateFilterDriverRegistry, FilterServiceName FFFFCB01F6F617D0
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]Reading DefaultFilterSettings from registry - Status 0xc0000034(STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND), Validation = 0 
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]==>ndisSetAllFilterDefaultParameters, FilterServiceName FFFFCB01F6F617D0 FilterRegistryPath FFFFCB01F6F61610 FilterParams FFFFF80DD6A88598
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]<==ndisSetAllFilterDefaultParameters, FilterServiceName FFFFCB01F6F617D0 FilterRegistryPath FFFFCB01F6F61610 FilterParams FFFFF80DD6A88598 Status 0
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]<==ndisCreateFilterDriverRegistry, FilterServiceName FFFFCB01F6F617D0 Status 0
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]>Begin filter driver's SetOptionsHandler. FilterDriver=FFFF8A85532E6010
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [mp]<End filter driver's SetOptionsHandler.   FilterDriver=FFFF8A85532E6010, Status=0x00000000
    [1]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [km]Begin PNP operations on miniport FFFF8A85538DC1A0
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.498 [km]End PNP operations on miniport FFFF8A85538DC1A0
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.499 [mp]<==NdisFRegisterFilterDriver, Status 0
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.499 [mp]==>NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: DriverObject FFFF8A85572FD6D0, Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP) (WiFi version)
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.499 [mp]==>ndisCreateFilterDriverRegistry, FilterServiceName FFFFCB01F6F618B0
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.499 [mp]Reading DefaultFilterSettings from registry - Status STATUS_SUCCESS, Validation = 0 
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.499 [mp]<==ndisCreateFilterDriverRegistry, FilterServiceName FFFFCB01F6F618B0 Status 0
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.499 [mp]NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: Cannot find filter 7daf2ac8-e9f6-4765-a842-f1f5d2501351 in the registry.  Did INetCfg install this filter successfully?
    [0]0004.015C::08/28/2016-20:26:58.499 [mp]<==NdisFRegisterFilterDriver, Status c0000001
```

So it seems that NDIS didn't find the 2nd filter's registry `7daf2ac8-e9f6-4765-a842-f1f5d2501351`. But I checked it in `regedit`. It has that key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\{7DAF2AC8-E9F6-4765-A842-F1F5D2501341}]
"InstallTimeStamp"=hex:e0,07,08,00,00,00,1c,00,0c,00,1a,00,39,00,88,03
"Characteristics"=dword:00040000
"ComponentId"="INSECURE_NPCAP"
"Description"="@oem11.inf,%npf_desc_standard%;Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP)"
"InfPath"="oem11.inf"
"InfSection"="FilterStandard"
"LocDescription"="@oem11.inf,%npf_desc_standard%;Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP)"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\{7DAF2AC8-E9F6-4765-A842-F1F5D2501341}\Ndi]
"TimeStamp"=hex:e0,07,08,00,00,00,1c,00,0c,00,1a,00,39,00,88,03
"HelpText"="A NDIS 6 filter driver & WFP callout driver to support packet capturing and sending under Windows 7, 8 & 10"
"Service"="npcap"
"CoServices"=hex(7):6e,00,70,00,63,00,61,00,70,00,00,00,00,00
"FilterClass"="compression"
"FilterType"=dword:00000002
"FilterRunType"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\{7DAF2AC8-E9F6-4765-A842-F1F5D2501341}\Ndi\Interfaces]
"LowerRange"="ndis5,ndis4"
"UpperRange"="noupper"
"FilterMediaTypes"="ethernet, fddi, wan, ppip, wlan, bluetooth, ndis5, vwifi, flpp4, flpp6, vchannel, nolower"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\{7DAF2AC8-E9F6-4765-A842-F1F5D2501351}]
"InstallTimeStamp"=hex:e0,07,08,00,00,00,1c,00,0c,00,1a,00,3a,00,7e,02
"Characteristics"=dword:00040000
"ComponentId"="INSECURE_NPCAP_WIFI"
"Description"="@oem11.inf,%npf_desc_wifi%;Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP) (Wi-Fi)"
"InfPath"="oem11.inf"
"InfSection"="FilterWiFi"
"LocDescription"="@oem11.inf,%npf_desc_wifi%;Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP) (Wi-Fi)"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\{7DAF2AC8-E9F6-4765-A842-F1F5D2501351}\Ndi]
"TimeStamp"=hex:e0,07,08,00,00,00,1c,00,0c,00,1a,00,3a,00,7e,02
"HelpText"="A NDIS 6 filter driver & WFP callout driver to support packet capturing and sending under Windows 7, 8 & 10"
"Service"="npcap_wifi"
"CoServices"=hex(7):6e,00,70,00,63,00,61,00,70,00,5f,00,77,00,69,00,66,00,69,\
  00,00,00,00,00
"FilterClass"="ms_medium_converter_128"
"FilterType"=dword:00000002
"FilterRunType"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4d36e974-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\{7DAF2AC8-E9F6-4765-A842-F1F5D2501351}\Ndi\Interfaces]
"LowerRange"="ndis5,ndis4"
"UpperRange"="noupper"
"FilterMediaTypes"="ethernet, fddi, wan, ppip, wlan, bluetooth, ndis5, vwifi, flpp4, flpp6, vchannel, nolower"
```

So I don't know why NDIS reports `NdisFRegisterFilterDriver: Cannot find filter 7daf2ac8-e9f6-4765-a842-f1f5d2501351 in the registry.  Did INetCfg install this filter successfully?`?

Answer (score 1):

A binary image (.sys file) can only be loaded by the system once at a time.  You cannot load the same image simultaneously for two different services.  (Nor can you load it once for a service, and once for a PNP driver.)  That means you will *always* see `DriverEntry`, `DriverUnload`, `DriverEntry`, `DriverUnload`, ....  You will never see `DriverEntry`, `DriverEntry`, `DriverUnload`, `DriverUnload`.

## Using a fake service

Each NDIS LWF or protocol driver needs a service, to hold some registry keys.  But here's the first trick: the service doesn't have to be running!  You can create a dummy service record for an LWF, then have some other service actually use the LWF.  NDIS doesn't validate the `ServiceName` you pass to `NdisFRegisterFilterDriver`.  (And yes, it's okay to rely on this trick.  I speak with the authority of the owner of NDIS at Microsoft.)

There is are built-in drivers that do exactly this.  Look at TCPIP and TCPIP6.  These are two different services, and also two different protocol drivers, but only one image (tcpip.sys).  The TCPIP service is the *real* service — it will actually be started at boot.  The TCPIP6 service is fake — it's marked to never start, and if you try to manually start it, it won't work.

(Aside: don't use WFPLWFS as an example.  Although it also has 3 filter drivers sharing 1 binary, it does something different that would result in a few problems if you tried to do it.  Also, starting with Windows 10, the INFs used by TCPIP and TCPIP6 are kind of fake, so you shouldn't assume that they're good examples of how to do this trick.)

You can optionally register all this with 1 INF or 2 INFs; it doesn't make much difference to the OS.  Let's say 1 INF, just to keep the example shorter.

So what you need are:

- LWF named FilterA
- LWF named FilterB
- Service named ServiceA
- Service named ServiceB
- Driver image named Driver.sys
- INF named Driver.inf

Let's say that ServiceA is the *real* service and ServiceB is the *fake* service.

Driver.inf would have:

```
[Manufacturer]
Contoso=Models,NTamd64

[Models.NTamd64]
"Cool Filter A"=FilterA, my_filter_a
"Awesome Filter B"=FilterB, my_filter_b

[FilterA]
NetCfgInstanceId="{guid-aaaa-guid}"
CopyFiles=copy.driver.sys
Characteristics=0x40000
AddReg=FilterA.reg

[FilterB]
NetCfgInstanceId="{guid-bbbb-guid}"
Characteristics=0x40000
AddReg=FilterB.reg

[FilterA.reg]
HKR,Ndi,Service,,"ServiceA"
HKR,etc,etc,etc

[FilterB.reg]
HKR,Ndi,Service,,"ServiceB"
HKR,etc,etc,etc

[FilterA.Services]
AddService=ServiceA,,FilterA.svc

[FilterB.Services]
AddService=ServiceB,,FilterB.svc

[FilterA.svc]
StartType = Demand
ServiceBinary = Driver.sys

[FilterB.svc]
StartType = Demand
ServiceBinary = Driver.sys

[copy.driver.sys]
driver.sys,,,2
```

Note that you register 2 LWFs, create 2 services, and copy 1 image.

You install that with 1 call to `SetupCopyOEMInf` and 2 calls to `INetCfgClassSetup::Install`, for each of `my_filter_a` and `my_filter_b`.

To start the driver, only start 1 service, ServiceA.  Never start the other dummy service.

But what if you don't want both filters running at the same time?  Easy — don't call `NdisFRegisterFilterDriver` until you want the LWF to actually be started.  You can always register/deregister your filter driver from an ioctl handler.  So your `DriverEntry` would be fairly empty — just create a device object to listen for ioctls.

## Using an export driver

A different option is to create 2 services that each have their own driver image.  But the driver image would be a thin wrapper around a call to a single shared export driver (like a DLL).  You can put all your real work in that shared export driver.

```
 ServiceA      ServiceB
     |             |
     |             |
DriverA.sys   DriverB.sys
     \             /
      \           /
     TheRealDriver.sys
```

This keeps it simple, although it does wind up with a pile of extra drivers.

Comment: I'm very intertested with your fake service way. In this way, I will see ``DriverEntry, DriverEntry, DriverUnload, DriverUnload``, right? And how about the services' uninstallation? Should I make 2 calls to ``INetCfgClassSetup::DeInstall``, for each of ``my_filter_a`` and ``my_filter_b``. Is there an order? Like first uninstall A then uninstall B? Thanks!